# Why is $\int_C {dz \over z - a} = 2 \pi i$ not a counter-example to Cauchy's theorem in a disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Cauchy's theorem in a disk states that if $\Delta$ is an open disk and $f$ is analytic on $\Delta$, then if $\gamma$ is a closed curve inside $\Delta$ we have that

$$
\int_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 0
$$

**Question:** Consider that if $C$ is the unit circle and $a$ does not intersect $C$, we have that

$$
\int_C {dz \over z - a} = 2 \pi i \ne 0
$$

Yet ${1 \over z - a}$ is analytic on the whole plane except in case $z = a$.  We can make $a$ as far away as we want from the origin, however.  So let $\Delta$ be a a disk of radius of $\rho > 1$ and $C$ the unit circle and $a$ the point $(\rho+1) + i(\rho+1)$.  How does this condition not violate Cauchy's theorem in a disk?

Comment: Read the conditions of Cauchy's theorem again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function $z\mapsto\dfrac{1}{z-a}$ is not analytic at $z=a$.

In fact,  if $a$ is in the exterior of the disk then Cauchy's theorem is applicable and the integral is $0$.  It is only if $a$ is in the interior of the disk, i.e. the curve over which one integrates winds around $a$ one in a counterclockwise direction, that the integral is $2\pi i$

Comment: But $z \mapsto {1 \over z -a}$ is analytic inside the $\rho$-disk $\Delta$ about the origin (so long as $a \notin \Delta$)

Comment: I just saw your edit -- that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Being $a$ near of far from the origin is irrerevant. The important fact is $\gamma$ enclose $a$? (the *singular* point)

Answer (score 0):

Because Cauchy's Theorem states that the function must be analytic both on and inside the closed curve(in this case C). If the point a is inside C,then the integrand is not analytic at this point. Hence the integral will not be zero.